Comparing みたいに and みたいな感じで
To preface, I understand that not every みたいな感じで is used adverbially like みたいに, because sometimes that で is the te-form:
素人みたいな感じで申し訳ないですが
Sorry to sound like an amateur. (I sound like an amateur, (and so) I'm sorry.
But in cases where it is adverbial, at first glance they seem the same but I have reason to believe they differ.
Taking an example from a caption of a twitter video where a cat quickly jolts to it's senses:

『あっ、おれ猫だった！！』みたいな感じで急に我に返るのやめてほしい。笑
"I want the cat to stop coming to it's senses like "Ah, I was a cat!""

1.) I am pretty sure みたいに could be used here. But I feel that みたいな感じで may be more common with turning a quotation into an adverb than みたいに. Does this have any merit? Or do they differ in other ways?
Incidentally, even though the use of the te form is different, sometimes I feel that it is used almost adverbially and am confused as to how it differs in meaning.
I will compare two more tweets to show this, the first being a  twitter caption from a video displaying a new ChatGPT model:

ここまで来ると不老不死が見えてくるよね
「仮に俺が肉体的に亡くなったとしても、俺の意思はAIで生き続ける」みたいな感じでww
"Coming to this point, you can see immortality, right? Like, "Even
if I physically pass away, my consciousness will live on"

The second is a tweet talking about the speaker's antipathy towards people who don't empathize when you complain, rebutting that there are still good things that happen to you:

これは完全に偏見だけど、弱音を吐いたときに 「でも定時で帰れるんだからいいじゃん」 「でも怒鳴られたりしないんだからいいじゃん」 みたいに
“でも＋当たり前の環境をさも恵まれているかのように例示” してくるやつは、総じて人間としての深みが致命的にない
"This is completely my bias, but when I whine, they're all like "but
you can go home at a regular time so it's okay" and "but you're not
yelled out so it's okay".
"The people who bring up
commonplace environments as if they are a blessing are generally fatally lacking
in depth as people"

In the first example, I see the で as the te form as a sentence end used as something like a reversal. In the second example the に ends the sentence, so to me there is something like an 言われる omitted. However, I am still unsure about my understanding and as confirmation I am curious as to how interchangeable they are in these two examples.
2.) Can you switch the みたいな感じで and みたいに in these examples? If so, how would the meaning and interpretation of the sentences be changed?

I would read the second example as 〜みたいな感じで（見えてくる） where で is a particle. As for the third, not sure why they put an empty line after みたいに. It seems to adverbially modify 〜してくる to me. Otherwise, the first part would be totally incomplete.

"Totally incomplete", but there's still times when the adverbial みたいな感じ at the end has an omitted verb though right? I can find some  examples where this seems to be the case (here I expect something like 言う). Unless this instead points to a trailing te-form when it is で?

They started the sentence with これは完全に偏見だけど. The first part has no 偏見 in it. Their 偏見 is that people who say such things all fatally lack depth as human beings. The first part is fatally incomplete, semantically speaking.
